# How do i make more spacing my my mui typography

Tags: material-ui

Ive got some typography that wraps as the box gets slimmer im looking for some sort of sx property that allows me to increase the line spacing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add inline css styles to the `Typography` component.

```
<Typography style={{ lineHeight: "24px" }}>
    ...something
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest approach is define it globally through [Theme Overrides.](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#global-theme-override).

```js
const theme = createTheme({
 components: {
    MuiTypography: {
      styleOverrides: {
        h1: {
          '&.MuiTypography-gutterBottom': {
            marginBottom: 32
          }
        },
        gutterBottom: {
          marginBottom: 8 //default e.g. body1/paragraphs
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```